# Postgres equivalent of DENSE_RANK FIRST

Tags: sql, postgresql, oracle, dense-rank

There are lots of questions asked about dense rank but most of them ask for a specific scenario. I converted the query into a more generic one. Could you convert that from oracle into postgres?

```
SELECT MAX(id) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY prop2 DESC) AS prop1 FROM table t);
```

Answer (score 0):

For this query, the equivalent would be:

```
select id
from table t
order by prop2 desc
limit 1;
```

Or for a version that works in both Oracle and Postgres:

```
select id
from table t
order by prop2 desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

Comment: Is it better to write Max instead of limit 1?

Comment: @YalinErenDeliorman . . . That wouldn't do what you want.